# How do I set maximum bandwidth in Chromecast CAF Receiver

Tags: chromecast

I can set `cast.framework.PlaybackConfig.initialBandwidth`. I am wondering is there a setting for max bandwidth throughout the playback.

Below is the manifest that I am receiving, Chromecast player is auto switching according to my current network speed. I want to set a max bandwidth to `2987000` so it can never go to `1080p`.

```
  <Representation bandwidth="79000" codecs="avc1.42000c" frameRate="2997/100" height="144" id="7c96d52b-6a35-406f-bcb8-d1fbdca1892c" width="256"></Representation>
  <Representation bandwidth="199000" codecs="avc1.42000c" frameRate="2997/100" height="160" id="6c20b31e-4503-4c58-ac87-e431ca0814b1" width="284"></Representation>
  <Representation bandwidth="349000" codecs="avc1.420015" frameRate="2997/100" height="240" id="5f38f276-918e-4b53-9e59-49828e8370e1" width="426"></Representation>
  <Representation bandwidth="597000" codecs="avc1.4d001e" frameRate="2997/100" height="360" id="f98c3885-6a69-40c1-b41d-cf497fe144db" width="640"></Representation>
  <Representation bandwidth="848000" codecs="avc1.4d001f" frameRate="2997/100" height="540" id="9efd598f-ab6a-48df-850a-f74e5787c35d" width="960"></Representation>
  <Representation bandwidth="1094000" codecs="avc1.4d001f" frameRate="2997/100" height="576" id="4a4c0dae-1e42-45cc-a0ec-c35ebc9a1d1b" width="1024"></Representation>
  <Representation bandwidth="1495000" codecs="avc1.4d001f" frameRate="2997/100" height="576" id="a023a254-0885-4ddf-895b-839f5cb384ce" width="1024"></Representation>
  <Representation bandwidth="1995000" codecs="avc1.64001f" frameRate="2997/100" height="720" id="1007e5e6-8400-4d92-bcd8-8cfdaf4dde1d" width="1280"></Representation>
  <Representation bandwidth="2987000" codecs="avc1.64001f" frameRate="2997/100" height="720" id="e0879e7b-19e3-4c65-8063-300411fc40bf" width="1280"></Representation>
  <Representation bandwidth="4482000" codecs="avc1.640028" frameRate="2997/100" height="1080" id="5576c06c-3a6a-4167-ba7a-803b424af204" width="1920"></Representation>
```

Comment: If you are referring to the bandwidth in each device, then it should be the router that would do some work. As it was not specified in the documentation that it is limited to a certain number. But this [posts from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/7p8685/how_to_control_bandwidth_provided_to_chromecast_2/) cited this scenarios.

Comment: Hi @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 , I need to set the restriction on the CAF receiver side. Thanks for the reply.